# What headers must be included to use wsprintf with MinGW

Tags: c, include, mingw

I seem to be able to compile code that calls `wsprintf` with the [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/) `gcc` if I have these includes (in this order):

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <wingdi.h>
#include <winuser.h>
```

But I feel like there might be some "cleaner" way to do this. Perhaps with only a single header inclusion. I arrived at this list by searching header files for missing symbols and then including headers one-by-one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Include `<Windows.h>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms647550%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean `swprintf()`?

`swprintf()` is described in the C99 standard. You need `<wchar.h>`.

If `wsprintf` does the same as `swprintf` you may want to consider using a standard function instead.

```
       7.24.2.3  The swprintf function

       Synopsis

       [#1]

               #include <wchar.h>
               int swprintf(wchar_t * restrict s,
                       size_t n,
                       const wchar_t * restrict format, ...);

       Description

       [#2] The swprintf function is equivalent to fwprintf, except
       that  the  argument  s specifies an array of wide characters
       into which the generated output is  to  be  written,  rather
       than  written  to  a stream.  No more than n wide characters
       are written, including a terminating  null  wide  character,
       which is always added (unless n is zero).
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the standard function `swprintf`? In that case you should include `wchar.h`.

Comment: no, `wsprintf`. I did try `wchar.h` at one point, but that didn't seem to work.

Comment: windows.h should work